# SQL query to aggregate amount from product transaction table

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

Need to aggregate latest product prices of all products from batchTransaction Table, relevant Columns:

- `id` - Unique
- `productId` - Not unique
- `transactionValue` - Value of that transaction
- `transactionDate` - date of that transaction

A product can have multiple transactions but only latest needs to be considered for aggregation. Need to aggregate total transactionValue across plant at a provided date, for all products.

```
SELECT SUM(transactionQuantity)
FROM batchTransaction
WHERE (id, dateCreated) IN (
    SELECT id, MAX(dateCreated)
    FROM batchTransaction
    WHERE AND transactionDate < 1675189800000
    GROUP BY productId
);
```

Above query would have worked, but it gives error - `this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: You mixed `SELECT id` and `GROUP BY productId` in the subquery.

Comment: Yes that's for reference. What would be the correct query?

Comment: As already suggested by @Atmo, for your query to be valid the join should be `WHERE (productId, dateCreated) IN ( SELECT productId, MAX(dateCreated)`. Beyond that, I cannot understand the intention of your aggregation. You should update your question with an example - given this sample data (markdown table) the expected result is this (markdown table).

Comment: Agreed, the concern is if a product is updated more than once on the same millisecond than it shall be aggregated multiple times by outer query.

Answer (score 0):

The only way this makes sense with your description of getting the latest transaction per product is to group by `productId` in the subquery, and use `productId` in the result. Then compare that to the `productid` in the outer query.

```
SELECT SUM(transactionQuantity)
FROM batchTransaction
WHERE (productId, dateCreated) IN (
    SELECT productId, MAX(dateCreated)
    FROM batchTransaction
    WHERE transactionDate < 1675189800000
    GROUP BY productId
);
```

I also removed a superfluous `AND` keyword from your subquery.

I assume from this that `transactionDate` is stored as a `BIGINT` representing the UNIX timestamp in milliseconds, not as a `DATETIME` type.

A more modern way to write this sort of query is to use a window function `ROW_NUMBER()` and select only those that are the first (latest) row in each partition by `productId`.

```
SELECT SUM(transactionQuantity)
FROM (
    SELECT transactionQuantity, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY productId ORDER BY dateCreated DESC) AS rownum
    FROM batchTransaction
    WHERE transactionDate < 1675189800000
) AS t
WHERE t.rownum = 1;
```

This syntax requires MySQL 8.0 for the window function.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid IN clause as it causes performance issue when run on a larger dataset. Join would be a better option in such scenarios.

The id in the IN clause, is not guaranteed that it is of latest transaction because when you do group by product id, records with same product id are grouped and the order of those records is not maintained as you are assuming.

Query to achieve the right results

```
select sum(t.transactionQuantity)
from
(select
  cast(substring_index(group_concat(
   transactionQuantity
   order by transactionDate desc separator ','
  ), ',', 1) as unsigned) as transactionQuantity
  from
  batchTransaction
  group by productId
) as t;
```